# Strange union type behavior in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, discriminated-union

Could anyone explain the following behavior in TypeScript (2.4.1)?

Scenario: I have a button which could be "red" or "red and round" (modifications). I would like to have the following syntax to describe it:

```
button.mods = "red";
button.mods = ["red", "round"];
button.mods = { red: true, round: false };
```

To describe all of this, I use the following interfaces:

```
interface HasMods<T extends string>{ 
    mods: T | T[] | { [key in T]?: boolean } 
}

interface Button extends HasMods<"round" | "red"> { 
}
```

Ok, now we can do some testing:

```
let b: Button;
b.mods = "red"; //ok, correct 
b.mods = "green"; //error, correct

b.mods = ["red"]; //ok, correct
b.mods = ["green"]; //error, correct

b.mods = {red: true}; //ok, correct
b.mods = {red: true, green: true}; //error, correct
```

So far everything is perfect.
But now a mystery:

```
b.mods = {red: true, map: false}; //ok, why ???
```

Why is the value "map" valid for my object of type { [key in T]?: boolean } where T is "red" | "round"? "map" is neither "red" or "round".

Actually, all array methods are valid here - "every", "copyWithin", etc...

Comment: I believe that by default typescript doesn't do extraneous key checking. It only verifies what needs to be in the object.

Comment: Why not? In {red: true, green: true} it perfectly identifies that red can be used, but green cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look in the **proto** definition of the array, "map" is one of the attributes.

So when you're comparing "map in T" it's true, because it's being compared inside an array structure, if it were an object it will be false

```js
console.log("map" in {"element":4}) // false
console.log("map" in [4]) //true
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But why is T an array? T should be of type "red" | "round" to the compiler.

Comment: `HasMods<"round" | "red">` *might* be an array, and that's just the way TypeScript [deals with](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14383) excess properties on union types.